# Is it possible to reinstall Raspbian on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: networking, installation, raspberry-pi

I have a Raspberry Pi and I need to get the image reinstalled but it's a 4 hour drive away to it. The OS is Raspbian and it is connected through an Ethernet connection. I can SSH into the Raspberry Pi just fine, but I need to find a way to remotely reinstall the OS on it.

I hear there is something called PXE Network Install that might be able to do this, but how would I go about doing this? The website doesn't really have much information on doing this.

Answer (score 2):

The Raspberry PI is not able to perform a network install "PXE style".
It always needs to boot a minimum kernel **from the SD** and from there the rest of the OS could be found from the net.

In your case Raspbian has an installer booting from the SD and next it retrieves all the Raspbian components from the internet.

read [here](https://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianInstaller) for more info